# Can I use a programmable gaming mouse for modelling

Tags: mouse

Hi I just wanted to know if I could use a gaming mouse (with programmable 6 button) and assign the extra buttons to some modelling tool hotkeys in blender. Is there any option to add the extra buttons on the mouse to add an assignment like that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem, just press the mouse button when setting up the shortcut and Blender will recognize it as `Button5 Mouse` for example.

You can also set the mouse keys in most mouse management software to act like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, etc.

Lastly check if there are good drivers for your gaming mouse if you are on Linux or MacOS.